# Textbox is empty after filling with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I create textbox by this code:

```
<div style="clear:left;">
    <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ID="selectText" ReadOnly="true" Width="560px" Height="50px"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

I fill it by this code:

```
elSelText.value = elSelText.value.substr(0, position) + chosenoption2.value + " ";
```

And then i try to send value in textbox to server, but it's empty!

```
protected void btnUseSelectClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sourceDetails.SelectCommand += " and " + selectText.Text;
        Session["FilterSelectCommand"] = sourceDetails.SelectCommand;
        tableResults.DataBind();
    }
```

On the advice I added AutoPostBack="true":

```
<div style="clear:left;">
    <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="selectText" ReadOnly="true" Width="560px" Height="50px"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

but it didn't help

Comment: Just a guess, but does removing `ReadOnly="true"` make a difference?

Comment: The value of the textbox is empty because the server doesn't know it has changed.  The server needs to be notified somehow.  Typically this is done with either a full or partial postback.

Comment: @Doc I think that's what `protected void btnUseSelectClick() { }` is for

Comment: @DStanley I don't think it would. The value wouldn't be submitted if it were `disabled`, but `readonly` shouldn't make a difference. I could be wrong though

Comment: @DStanley, you advice helped me but what if it important to stay textbox readonly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's news to me, it seems that the `ReadOnly` property doesn't keep track of changes from the client. If you want the "readonly" functionality but still get the value on the server, put the following in your `Page_Load` method:

```
selectText.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

And remove the `ReadOnly` (and `AutoPostBack`) property in the `<asp:TextBox>` tag.

( From: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2006/04/12/16409.aspx and http://forums.asp.net/t/1467081.aspx - it was a fairly quick find with Google)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a problems of ViewState. Try add the check of `Page.IsPostBack` in the page load event like this:

```cs
If(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // Data binding for the first call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to ReadOnly: ASP.Net registers which controls are readonly when sending you the page.

The value of these controls is discarded when posting back, and it is regotten (from ViewState I believe).

A workaround for this would be not setting `readonly="true"` on the aspx page, but setting it with `$(document).ready(your_function_here();)` (if you're using jQuery) or with the body `onLoad` event.